# svn copy command

Tags: svn, branch, branching-and-merging

I understand that this a very noob problem, but when I try to create a new branch from already present branch (not trunk) with the command :

```
svn copy svn+ssh://svn.example.com/software/branches/branch_name svn+ssh://svn.example.com/software/branches/new_branch_name  -m "Message"
```

I get the following error :

> svn: No repository found in 'svn+ssh://svn.example.com/software/branches'

I have checked again and again, the directory is correct. I don't understand why this is happening.

Comment: What does `svn info svn+ssh://svn.example.com/software/branches` say?

Comment: @malenkiy_scot : its says the same thing 'svn: No repository found in 'svn+ssh://svn.example.com/software/branches''

Comment: Ok, what about `svn info svn+ssh://svn.example.com/software`?

Comment: Are you _sure_ you are useing the `svn+ssh` protocol?

Comment: same error : svn: No repository found in .....

Comment: @Wrikken : yes pretty much sure, just a couple of minutes ago I deleted my branch using svn+ssh

Comment: @Aaditya, googling for `"svn+ssh" "no repository found"` produces quite a long list of hits. You can start going over it as it may take a while until someone answers your question. Many of them have a common theme of specifying the full path.

Comment: Ahh finally figured out the mistake... the command should have been svn copy svn+ssh://user@svn.example.com/software/branches/branch_name svn+ssh://user@svn.example.com/software/branches/new_branch_name  -m "Message"  it is working fine now :D

Comment: @Aaditya, please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ahh finally figured out the mistake... the command should have been :-

`svn copy svn+ssh://user@svn.example.com/software/branches/branch_name svn+ssh://user@svn.example.com/software/branches/new_branch_name -m "Message"`

I missed out the user part, which wasn't given in the guide.

it works absolutely fine now :D