# Commiting using tortoise SVN

Tags: svn, merge, tortoisesvn, commit

I have made changes to a file in my repository, and I want to commit those changes, using tortoise svn, so I right clicked on the folder, and tries to commit the file, but it showed the following errors :-

'Error Commit failed (Details follow)
Can't create directory '/svnroot/db/transactions/31383-1.txt : Permission denied'

I use svn+ssh protocol, and If I correctly remember, I haven't entered my password, anywhere so this may be the error due to not entering the password. Can you please tell me how can I get rid of the error/enter the ssh key ?

Comment: How exactly did you checkout your WC? More specifically, what URL did you specify?

Comment: @malenkiy_scot : just created a folder and right clicked -> svn checkout, and then the link :- [link]http://svn.example.com/branches/...

Comment: @malenkiy_scot : should I have used svn+ssh://svn.example.com  instead of http and then the website ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I have to add an extra phrase to the address svn+ssh://user@svn.example.com/**svnroot**/branches...

svnroot had to be added to the address,

no error now :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the [same problem you had yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11013729/svn-copy-command). You need to do `svn+ssh://user@...` Otherwise you are using anonymous access which is read-only.

Try relocating your working copy to `svn+ssh://user@svn.example.com`. In Tortoise SVN you do it like this: right click on your working copy -> TortoiseSVN -> Relocate. Modify the URL that appears to `svn+ssh://user@svn.example.com` format -> OK.

Comment: I think you are correct, "this is the problem", but when I try to do TortoiseSVN -> Relocate, it shows me repository doesn't exist at the address : Error

Comment: It may be because I haven't added my user name/passwd anywhere till now, Is there a place where I should add it ?

Comment: What does the URL say before you try to modify it: ssh or http?

Comment: If it is HTTP, try the following: right click -> TortoiseSVN -> Settings -> Saved Data -> push Clear next to Authentication Data.

Comment: Authentication Data can't be selected it is greyed

Comment: Ok, last try: can you check out a fresh WC with `svn+ssh://user@...`?